# How to form oracle function - TIMESTAMP input -Date Math - Number Return

Tags: oracle, sql-function

I am trying to create an oracle function that takes a TIMESTAMP input, calculates number of days between that timestamp and today, and returns that number. I am not constructing it properly, and not sure how to fix:

```
create or replace FUNCTION "DAYSSINCEOPENDATE" (OPENDATE IN TIMESTAMP) 
   RETURN NUMBER
   AS
   retval  NUMBER;

        BEGIN
           SELECT (SYSDATE - CAST(OPENDATE AS DATE) FROM DUAL)) into retval;
           return retval;
        END;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `select ... into ... from ...`

Comment: yes I am sort of aware of the general construction (select into from). I assumed that the select into part is: "Select into retval", and the the from clause involved something with my "(SYSDATE - CAST(OPENDATE AS DATE) FROM DUAL))", but could not get a structure that compiled. so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aleksej said in a comment, [the order of your clauses is incorrect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90); you need

```
SELECT SYSDATE - CAST(OPENDATE AS DATE) into retval FROM DUAL;
```

So:

```
create or replace FUNCTION "DAYSSINCEOPENDATE" (OPENDATE IN TIMESTAMP) 
   RETURN NUMBER
   AS
   retval  NUMBER;

        BEGIN
           SELECT SYSDATE - CAST(OPENDATE AS DATE) into retval FROM DUAL;
           return retval;
        END;
/

select DAYSSINCEOPENDATE(timestamp '2018-01-01 12:13:14.5') from dual;

DAYSSINCEOPENDATE(TIMESTAMP'2018-01-0112:13:14.5')
--------------------------------------------------
                                        204.773368
```

You don't actually need the `retval` variable or the query against `dual` though; you can simplify that to

```
create or replace FUNCTION "DAYSSINCEOPENDATE" (OPENDATE IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
   return SYSDATE - CAST(OPENDATE AS DATE);
END;
/

select DAYSSINCEOPENDATE(timestamp '2018-01-01 12:13:14.5') from dual;

DAYSSINCEOPENDATE(TIMESTAMP'2018-01-0112:13:14.5')
--------------------------------------------------
                                        204.773368
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question and will check this answer.